# Unresolved call error

Tags: acceleo

I am trying to generate Hibernate with Acceleo 2.6, I have downloaded Hibernate init files from http://www.acceleo.org/wiki/index.php/UML_to_JEE_:_First_applications_with_JEE_module but when I launch chain file I get this error:

> -> Errors in file : /src/DaoFactory.java
>   Position 8 : EVAL : Unresolved call "baseImports", in file : /org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.dao/org/acceleo/module/pim/uml21/gen/java/dao/api/dao-common.mt, at line : 69, at column : 2, for object : fragment=_qb8akM37EdqwVrslYOdUDA file=/resource/testing/model/Better.uml
>   Position 9 : EVAL : Unresolved call "projectName", in file : /org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.dao/org/acceleo/module/pim/uml21/gen/java/dao/api/dao-common.mt, at line : 69, at column : 18, for object : fragment=_qb8akM37EdqwVrslYOdUDA file=/resource/testing/model/Better.uml
>   Position 9 : EVAL : Unresolved call "insertInPackage", in file : /org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.dao/org/acceleo/module/pim/uml21/gen/java/dao/api/dao-common.mt, at line : 69, at column : 33, for object : fragment=_qb8akM37EdqwVrslYOdUDA file=/resource/testing/model/Better.uml
>   Position 94 : EVAL : Unresolved call "importDaoException", in file : /org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.dao/src/org/acceleo/module/pim/uml21/gen/java/dao/api/dao-factory.mt, at line : 37, at column : 2, for object : fragment=_qb8akM37EdqwVrslYOdUDA file=/resource/testing/model/Better.uml
>   Position 263 : EVAL : Unresolved call "projectName", in file : /org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.dao/src/org/acceleo/module/pim/uml21/gen/java/dao/api/dao-factory.mt, at line : 46, at column : 15, for object : fragment=_qb8akM37EdqwVrslYOdUDA file=/resource/testing/model/Better.uml
>   Position 911 : EVAL : Unresolved call "projectName", in file : /org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.dao/src/org/acceleo/module/pim/uml21/gen/java/dao/api/dao-factory.mt, at line : 65, at column : 16, for object : fragment=_qb8akM37EdqwVrslYOdUDA file=/resource/testing/model/Better.uml

(see revision history for more of same)

Can someone please tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

The messages seem to indicate that Acceleo can't find the modules in which common generation behaviour is done.

Can you find the module "org.acceleo.module.pim.uml21.gen.java.common"?
You need this module to be able to generate properly.

It can be found [at the acceleo 2.x modules forge](http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=acceleo&path=/trunk/modules/community/uml21/jee/trunk/modules/)